# How to create a dictionary of capitals and governors of states

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary of the capitals and governors and then later choose a random state to ask the user what the capital of **_ is or who the governor of _** is. I have

```
import random

def state_dict():
    states={"Alabama":["montgomery","kay ivey"],"Alaska":["Juneau","Bill 
    Wallker"]}

def main():
    question_list=["What is the capital of","Who is the governor of"]
    choose_question=random.choice(question_list)
    if choose_question=="What is the capital of":
        choose_state= random.choice(states_dict)
        print("What is the capital of",choose_state)

    elif choose_question=="Who is the governor of":
        choose_state_2= random.choice(states_dict)
        print("Who is the governor of", choose_state_2)

main()
```

I get an error that states is undefined and I am unable to figure out why.

Comment: 1. Use return statement in state_dict() function. 2. replace statement choose_state= random.choice(states_dict) by choose_state= random.choice(states_dict().keys()).

Comment: Please post the Traceback.

Comment: [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).  Don't *create* `states` in a function, *create* it in the module.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a function for a static dict like `states` and also no main function. You can simplify this a lot:

```
states = {
    "Alabama": ["Montgomery", "Kay Ivey"],
    "Alaska": ["Juneau", "Bill Wallker"]
}
question_list = ["What is the capital of", "Who is the governor of"]

choose_state= random.choice(states)
choose_question = random.randint(0, 1)  # just an index that can be reused
answer = input(question_list[choose_question], choose_state)
if answer == states[choose_state][choose_question]:
    # yay
else:
    # aww
```

Answer (score 0):

Update2:
As @schwobaseggl has pointed out there's no reason to use the function states_dict() here. Just do

```
def main():
    states_dict = {
        "Alabama": ["montgomery", "kay ivey"],
        "Alaska": ["Juneau", "Bill Wallker"],
        }
    question_list = ["What is the capital of","Who is the governor of"]
    choose_question = random.choice(question_list)
    if choose_question == "What is the capital of":
        choose_state = random.choice(list(states_dict.keys()))  # this will give you a random key from the dict.
```

Also, you should study the PEP8 style guide and incorporate it in your muscle memory now.

---

Update:

```
def state_dict():
    states={"Alabama":["montgomery","kay ivey"],"Alaska":["Juneau","Bill 
    Wallker"]}
    return states  # returned states dict.

def main():
    question_list=["What is the capital of","Who is the governor of"]
    choose_question=random.choice(question_list)
    if choose_question=="What is the capital of":
        choose_state= random.choice(states_dict())  # added ()
        print("What is the capital of",choose_state)
```

---

Original:
You indentation is incorrect.

```
def state_dict():
states={"Alabama":["montgomery","kay ivey"],"Alaska":["Juneau","Bill 
Wallker"]}
```

states is outside the function state_dict(). Make it:

```
def state_dict():
    states={"Alabama":["montgomery","kay ivey"],"Alaska":["Juneau","Bill 
Wallker"]}
```

Additionally, you haven't followed the PEP8 style guidelines, maybe you did and compacted the code for SO. For those reading, this is a better way to format the code:

```
def state_dict():
    states = {
        "Alabama": ["montgomery", "kay ivey"],
        "Alaska": ["Juneau", "Bill Wallker"],
        }
```

Comment: I have it like that in my program sorry I wrote it wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your dictionary in this type of format?

`states = {'Alabama': {'capital': 'Montgomery', 'governor':'Kay Ivey'....}`

It flows more like Json data that way.

Plus here in your question,

`def state_dict():
    states={"Alabama":["montgomery","kay ivey"],"Alaska":["Juneau","Bill 
    Wallker"]}`

You don't return the `states` dict. So when you use it in `random.choice(state_dict())` you never end up passing the `states` dict to `random.choice(state_dict())`

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Ajax1234 noted your indentation in `state_dict` is off and you need to add `return states`
2. Your function is `state_dict` but you're calling `states_dict`
3. You need to switch `random.choice(states_dict)` to `random.choice(states_dict())`

If you fix 1 & 3 you should be good to go.